# Front end Entry form with validation error support?

Tags: form

The official example ( https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form ) seems to assume that the form itself is not already on a page which is an Entry. Dropping this form into a template that has an entry loaded already spits out that entry's entry.title or entry.body.

How should this work? We want the "new entry form" to live on a page that the client controls the content for.

Answer (score 1):

The `saveEntry` controller used by the default example returns an `entry` variable with the newly created item and the applicable error messages. This could be a potential cause of conflict if you have another variable called `entry`, which is by default pre-loaded in entry templates.

I think you could create a (for example) `product.twig` template and manually set an entry variable (via ID or slug) called anything else than `entry`.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you are suggesting. Thanks. A bit of a PITA though as that will cause issues with template fragments that need the "create entry" entry - things like SEOmatic.

Shame we can't define the variable name that the saveEntry controller spits back :/

Comment: Well as a workaround you can save the form with an ajax request. In this case, the controller will return a JSON object that you will need to handle via js... not sure if this will translate less work :)